# Why do some built-in constructors begin with a lower case letter?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Why do some constructors like `int()`, `list()`, `set()` and many others starts with a lower case letter instead of upper case? Shouldn't this be written `Int()`, `List()`, `Set()` and so on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These types were original factory functions, not types. As such they got a lower-case name:

```
$ python1.5
Python 1.5.2 (#1, Apr  1 2009, 22:55:54)  [GCC 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat
4.1.2-27)] on linux2
Copyright 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam
>>> type(int)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

That they are now types anyway is a historical artefact

All built-in types now follow this convention, including `set` and `frozenset`, which were added after the type unification that made `int` et al types.

Comment: of course Martijn Pieters has Python 1.5 installed :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I've got a `0.9.1` lying around (and [so can you](https://www.python.org/download/releases/early/))

Answer (score 7):

Despite the historical reason for most of these, builtin names that abide to Pythons' naming conventions don't use CapWords. This is specified in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names):

> Note that there is a separate convention for builtin names: most builtin names are single words (or two words run together), with the CapWords convention used only for exception names and builtin constants.

Comment: It's more that that has been grandfathered in now.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said *most* of these, @MartijnPieters. How much this historical precedent influenced the naming rules is another issue which I'd be interested to know :-)